# Blob Store to Blob Store

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, data-transfer, azcopy

I'm currently working on a project for one our managed services clients.
We're looking to take data out of their blob store (a) and move it into another blob store (b) using AzCopy.

My question is will blob store B update from blob store (b) when new data arrives or will we have to do a full copy each time we want to move new data across?

Seems like a silly question however I couldn't find out online the answer to my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AZCopy is just a command line tool that will allow you to copy blob x or container y from storage account A to storage account B, it's not doing anything special. If a blob already exists it will give you the option to not copy or to overwrite, like any normal copy operation.

The choice of what it copies will be down to the script you are running that triggers AZCopy, what are  you telling it to copy?

You also might want to look at Azure Data Factory for doing blob to blob copies.

Comment: Would you recommend using another tool for transferring data between storage accounts? The only issue is I'm transferring Azure Backup data between subscriptions!